# Multiple Combobox

Tags: sql, combobox

Because the only solution found for the moment is Form+VBA on french forums, I just would like to be sure that an SQL English spoken guru will not find the solution I'm dreaming of.

We have these tables :

```
T_Animals  : Contain Type and SubType + Dog name and other informations
T_Types    : can be Dog, Cat, Fish...
T_SubTypes : can be Husky for Dogs, Siamese Cat for cats...
```

To Fill the combo for T_AnimalsTypes, it's quite easy :

```
SELECT [T_Types].IdPK, [T_Types].[Description] FROM T_Types ORDER BY [Description];
```

The T_SubTypes table contain these fields :

```
IdPK : Primary Key
Description : the sub type string
TypeFK : Foreign key in T_Types
```

To fill the SubTypes combo, it must be based on Types combo (to filters all Dogs for example).
Is there a way to do this inside Table edition without VBA or forms ?

Thanks,

Vincent

Comment: Please specify the database software you are using.

Comment: I'm using Access 2013.